# Map MKAnnotaionView Customise

Tags: iphone, objective-c, dictionary

Customise annotaion view just like the yelp application with lot of details. [Yelp](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/yelp/id284910350?mt=8)

Is there a tuiitorial to customise the annotaion view like the one in the screen shots?

Please help.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Recently I had to develop an app using [`MKMapView`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKMapView_Class/MKMapView/MKMapView.html) using custom callouts (annotations). You won't get around subclassing `MKAnnotationView` if you want to do a lot of customizations to it.

What helped me most were those tutorials:

**Intro Tutorial**: http://mithin.in/2009/06/22/using-iphone-sdk-mapkit-framework-a-tutorial

**Part 1**: http://blog.asolutions.com/2010/09/building-custom-map-annotation-callouts-part-1/

**Part 2**: http://blog.asolutions.com/2010/09/building-custom-map-annotation-callouts-part-2/ (Also handles buttons inside your callout)

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
- (MKAnnotationView *) mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>) annotation
{
    MKPinAnnotationView *annView=[[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:@"currentloc"];
    annView.pinColor = MKPinAnnotationColorPurple;
    annView.animatesDrop=TRUE;
    annView.canShowCallout = YES;
    annView.calloutOffset = CGPointMake(-5, 5);

    [rightButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"demo_img.jpg"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    annView.leftCalloutAccessoryView=rightButton;//add image on mapView
    return annView;
}
```

Comment: other than the button there are a lot of changes... pls check the yelp itunes link